# MERN stack herokuapp does not work in edge and firefox browser. CORS preflight error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors

I have build a React Redux app. It works fine in localhost in every browser(chrome,edge,firefox). But the Heroku deployed app doesn't works in **Edge**, **Firefox** , although it worked in chrome perfectly.
My app doesn't seems to send request and receive response ,because i noticed that the login button spinner keeps on spinning because it waits for response. So i think that no response is received from backend.

Following are the conclusion i made after test in different browser:

1. it works perfectly in every browser in localhost development mode.
2. After Deploying , herokuapp works perfectly fine in chrome only.
3. Herokuapp  doesn't work in **edge** , **Firefox**.
4. Same is the issue with other system(Friends PC).
5. It doesn't work in any browser **except chrome** in **Mobile device**

**After console logging and banging my head for hours i got the following error in microsoft edge:**

```html
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ecrypt.herokuapp.com/user/login' from origin 'http://ecrypt.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://ecrypt.herokuapp.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
2.2c59d01c.chunk.js:2 POST https://ecrypt.herokuapp.com/user/login net::ERR_FAILED
```

Okay, so i figured out that there is some problem with CORS.

*Following is my code*
Frontend:

```html
import axios from "axios";

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://ecrypt.herokuapp.com",
  // withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token",
  },
});

// const API = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:9000" });

const cloudinaryAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ecryptimgdb",
});

//register new user
export const registerNewUser = (formData) =>
  API.post("/user/register", formData);

//Account Activation through Email
export const activation = (activation_token) =>
  API.post("/user/activation", {
    data: {
      activation_token,
    },
  });

//Login
export const login = (formData) =>
  API.post("/user/login", formData, { withCredentials: true });

//get Token
export const getToken = () =>
  API.post("/user/refresh_token", null, { withCredentials: true });
//Logout
export const logout = () => API.get("/user/logout", { withCredentials: true });
//get User

export const getUser = (token) =>
  API.get("/user/info", {
    headers: { Authorization: `${token}` },
  });
//PROFILE SETTINGS__________________________________________________________________________________________
export const editProfile = (token, profileData) =>
  API.post(
    "/user/updateProfile",
    { profileData },
    {
      headers: { Authorization: `${token}` },
    }
  );
//forgot password____
export const forgotPass = (email) =>
  API.post("/user/forgotPassword", { email });

//reset password_____
export const resetPass = (token, password) =>
  API.post(
    "/user/resetPassword",
    { password },
    {
      headers: { Authorization: `${token}` },
    }
  );
//change password____
export const changePass = (oldPassword, newPassword, token) =>
  API.post(
    "/user/changePassword",
    { oldPassword, newPassword },
    {
      headers: { Authorization: `${token}` },
    }
  );
```

BACKEND:

```html
//IMPORTS
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookiesParser = require("cookie-parser");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

// app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "https://ecrypt.herokuapp.com" }));
app.use(cookiesParser());
// app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
// const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGODB_LOCAL_URL;

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
//MONGODB CLOUD DATABASE CONNECTION________________________
mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to Database :: MongoDB Cloud"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));

// app.use("/", routesIndex);
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
//SERVER LISTENING
app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(`Listening on localhost:${PORT}`);
  }
});
```

**NOTE**
I am using cookies to store token so i needed withCredentials and Authorization headers.

Answer (score 0):

The following headers should be sent by the server (instead of the front)

```
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token",
  },
```

Comment: CORS is a client side solution to avoid an attaker could inject malicious code into a vulnerable site to attack other websites (XSS).

Comment: u mean at frontend should i remove all the headers, and insert them at server side in app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
}

Comment: Yes. I guess your static files are deployed in a domain and the API you are calling in a different one (domain or subdomain).  Notice that your server should check the origin domain before adding headers so that nobody could attack your API via XSS.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing headers from your axios request. I don't think those headers are allowed.

Answer (score -1):

**Ok, so i figured it out ,in my case i was setting headers as**

```
 {
  headers: { Authorization: `${token}` },
 }
```

**Instead of setting it like above a slight change just worked for me:**

```
{
 headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
}
```

**and at backend side in index.js or server.js whatever your file name is ,use cors middle ware like this:**

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://blahblah.herokuapp.com", "http://localhost:****"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

Note: credentials true if you want to pass cookies and access them at server side.
In my case i wanted to access the HttpOnly cookies at server side.